# Cannot set property '01' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var myObj = [

    {'name': 'Mike', 'number' : 'b1' , 'level' : 0 },
    {'name': 'Tom', 'number' : 'b2' , 'level' : 0 }
];

var result = _.map(myObj, _.invert);
```

Now, the result is:

```
[ { '0': 'level', Mike: 'name', b1: 'number' },
  { '0': 'level', Tom: 'name', b2: 'number' } ]
```

Ok, until here.

Then, I am adding to the result some parts and trying to fill them:

```
result = result,
    parts = {'levels': {}, 'names': {}, 'numbers': {}};

result.forEach(function(obj,i){

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) { 

        parts[k +"s"][k +(i+1)] = obj[k];
    });
});
```

but I am receiving :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '01' of undefined
```

at the `parts[k +"s"][k +(i+1)] = obj[k];`

Just note ,that if I don't use the `invert` , code runs without problems.

Comment: Obviously `parts[k +"s"]` is undefined. Not sure why you thought otherwise, not what you are attempting to do.

Comment: `parts[k +"s"][k +(i+1)] = obj[k];` => `parts[k +"s"]=parts[k +"s"]||{};parts[k +"s"][k +(i+1)] = obj[k];`

Comment: Why do you use  `_.inverse` at all? If you inverse the key and values then you for sure  need to _inverse_ the `k` and `obj[k]` also: `parts[obj[k] +"s"][obj[k] +(i+1)] = k;`

Comment: @t.niese:This will give me exactly the same output..

Comment: Then you need to tell what result you want to have. If you just say `that if I don't use the invert , code runs without problems` then this indicats that is produces the expected result, because there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change this:

```
result.forEach(function(obj,i){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        parts[k +"s"][k +(i+1)] = obj[k];
    });
});
```

To this:

```
result.forEach(function(obj, i){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) { 
        let box = parts[obj[k] + 's'][k];
        if(box) {
            if(Array.isArray(box)) {
                box.push(obj[k] + (i + 1));
            } else {
                parts[obj[k] + 's'][k] = [box, parts[obj[k] + 's'][k].slice(0, -1) + (i + 1)];
            }
            return;
        }

        parts[obj[k] + 's'][k] = obj[k] + (i + 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: :The `[k+(i+1)]` is because I am incrementing for example the names in order to have `    "names": {
        "name1": "Mike",
        "name2": "Tom"
    },
` ( I am speaking before using the invert).Now,I just want to have the opposite `("Mike":"name1","Tom":"name2")`

Comment: @George Have a look at this (updated). It gives weird results for `levels` because you have 2 keys equal to `0` so in the `parts.levels` you just have 1 key `0`. But apparently that's what you wanted. You might want to select another way of storing the data, since it is duplicated in some cases.

Comment: :Hmm.Very good!The only thing is that ,because the `level` filed has value `0` two times, it appears `"levels": {
        "0": "level2"
    },`.Is there a way to appear something like: `"levels": {
        "0": {"level1","level2"}
    },`?

Comment: `{"level1","level2"}` or `[ 'level1', 'level2']`? Array would be more suitable.

Comment: @George I updated my answer. Now if you get more 2 or more identical `levels` then `parts.levels` get converted to array and new values are pushed into that array.

Comment: I just updated it for the last time, now it works as it should. You're welcome.